# How to suppress "page not found" messages in watchdog

Tags: 8, log-messages

The issue `Add an option to suppress page not found watchdog messages` at https://www.drupal.org/node/2836458 indicates that a setting was added to Drupal 8 to suppress page not found errors in watchdog. I can't find the setting in the interface. Am I mistaken in understanding that it was added? If not, where do I find this setting? Running Drupal 8.8.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that option is available as described in the linked issue.

Make sure you have the Redirect 404 module enabled, visit `/admin/config/search/redirect/settings`, and select the *Suppress 'page not found' log messages* option.

[image: Configuration form screenshot]

That will stop 404s being logged.

Comment: Thanks, @Clive. I don't see the Redirect 404 module as being available for Drupal 8. Am I missing something there? Ah! I see it's in core. I'l try it out and report.

Comment: Oh right, it’s part of the normal redirect module (as a submodule) in D8  @Marshall

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks again, @Clive. Enabling 404 Redirect was it. It's always the one little thing I miss that catches me.